# git clone --recursive hangs counting objects

Tags: git

I'm trying to build openwrt.
The build hangs trying to clone `odhcpd`.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/sbyx/odhcpd.git odhcpd-2015-03-06 --recursive
Cloning into 'odhcpd-2015-03-06'...
remote: Counting objects: 1085, done.
```

Here's the verbose output:

```
$ set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git clone git://github.com/sbyx/odhcpd.git odhcpd-2015-03-06 --recursive -v -v; set +x
+ GIT_TRACE=2
+ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2
+ git clone git://github.com/sbyx/odhcpd.git odhcpd-2015-03-06 --recursive -v -v
13:27:43.855500 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'git://github.com/sbyx/odhcpd.git' 'odhcpd-2015-03-06' '--recursive' '-v' '-v'
Cloning into 'odhcpd-2015-03-06'...
13:27:44.386230 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> git-upload-pack /sbyx/odhcpd.git\0host=github.com\0
13:27:44.694096 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2:2.6.5~peff-show-branch-overflow-1680-gfcfb4db
13:27:44.694131 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1 refs/heads/master
13:27:44.694139 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< b564819c4856b666e0a7d40b6f25ba84c120bcd7 refs/heads/revert-46-master
13:27:44.694145 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< 343497f550eac6ce97d6718a0289df61814ee455 refs/pull/1/head
13:27:44.694151 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< cca650ba98a7439d2de757abcef38c05135242cb refs/pull/1/merge
13:27:44.694157 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< 0000
13:27:44.694829 shallow.c:313           shallow: prepare_shallow_info
Server supports multi_ack_detailed
Server supports side-band-64k
Server supports ofs-delta
Server version is git/2:2.6.5~peff-show-branch-overflow-1680-gfcfb4db
want 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1 (HEAD)
want 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1 (refs/heads/master)
want b564819c4856b666e0a7d40b6f25ba84c120bcd7 (refs/heads/revert-46-master)
13:27:44.695058 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> want 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1 multi_ack_detailed side-band-64k thin-pack ofs-delta agent=git/2.7.4
13:27:44.695068 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> want 6292fcd5c2b73cdc3cbc8942672cf7a4173354b1
13:27:44.695073 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> want b564819c4856b666e0a7d40b6f25ba84c120bcd7
13:27:44.695077 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> 0000
13:27:44.695306 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone> done
done
13:27:45.147711 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        clone< NAK
13:27:45.147852 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 17617 on asrolabe-VirtualBox' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
13:27:45.148109 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 17617 on asrolabe-VirtualBox' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
13:27:45.149108 trace.c:318             setup: git_dir: /home/asrolabe/Documents/openwrt-trunk/tmp/dl/odhcpd-2015-03-06/.git
13:27:45.149135 trace.c:319             setup: git_common_dir: /home/asrolabe/Documents/openwrt-trunk/tmp/dl/odhcpd-2015-03-06/.git
13:27:45.149139 trace.c:320             setup: worktree: /home/asrolabe/Documents/openwrt-trunk/tmp/dl
13:27:45.149142 trace.c:321             setup: cwd: /home/asrolabe/Documents/openwrt-trunk/tmp/dl
13:27:45.149144 trace.c:322             setup: prefix: (null)
13:27:45.149147 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 17617 on asrolabe-VirtualBox' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
13:27:45.152843 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Counting objects: 1085, done.
remote: Counting objects: 1085, done.
```

How can I fix this?

## EDIT 1

The clone works with `http:`

```
$ git clone http://github.com/sbyx/odhcpd.git odhcpd-2015-03-06 --recursive
```